# Rails has_one :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, rails-models

Rails has a `has_one :through` association that helps set up a one-to-one association with a third model by going through a second model. What is the real use of that besides making a shortcut association, that would otherwise be an extra step away.

Taking this example from the Rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
  has_one :account_history, :through => :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_one :account_history
end

class AccountHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

might allow us to do something like:

```
supplier.account_history
```

which would otherwise be reached as:

```
supplier.account.history
```

If it's only for simpler access then technically there could be a one-to-one association that connects a model with some nth model going through n-1 models for easier access. Is there anything else to it that I am missing besides the shortcut?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I've been struggling for a couple days on trying to get this to work without knowing that i needed the :through directive.  All better now.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. **Logic**, OK it might sound a bit weak for this but it would be logical to say that "I have a supplier who has an account with me, I want to see the entire account history of this supplier", so it makes sense for me to be able to access account history from supplier directly.
2. **Efficiency**, this for me is the main reason I would use `:through`, simply because this issues a join statement rather than calling supplier, and then account, and then account_history. noticed the number of database calls?

   - using `:through`, 1 call to get the supplier, 1 call to get account_history (rails automatically uses `:join` to retrieve through account)
   - using normal association, 1 call to get supplier, 1 call to get account, and 1 call to get account_history

That's what I think =) hope it helps!

Comment: I think the logic argument is pretty valid. Sounds more natural to say, get me this supplier's account history and not supplier's account's history. Very subtle but still easier to remember considering Ruby/Rails philosophy of flowing sentences rather than code. I know we can see the actual DB queries being issued but does Rails specify how these method calls would translate to SQL?

Comment: This also avoids violating the Law of Demeter.

Comment: @TomCrayford, I don't really see how it does. Doesn't this make the relation less direct?

Comment: @JasperKennis the physical relationship is less direct, but assuming other reasons for not directly linking the tables (like the fact that denormalizing supplier_id from account to account_history requires a callback and a small amount more storage space), this makes it so that you don't have to write a chain of methods every time you access account history through a supplier. And if the table in between changes at some later point, you won't have to rewrite method calls throughout your application. You'll only have to change the association(s).

Comment: Let's also not forget about avoiding a scenario where you may need to call another class method from within a class, for a very simple operation, and dont want to create an interface or service object for what may be a brutally simple data request. `has_one :through` is a lot cleaner for performing operations on tertiary relational data, than injecting or instantiating the tertiary class in the calling class.

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised no one has touched on **Association Objects**.

A `has_many` (or `has_one`) `:through` relationship facilitates the use of the **[association object pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308144825/http://dirkriehle.com/computer-science/programming/patterns/association-objects/associaton-object.html)** which is when you have two things related to each other, and that relation itself has attributes (ie a date when the association was made or when it expires).

This is [considered by some](https://web.archive.org/web/20141020145934/http://kevmcnamee.com/blog/2012/11/07/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many-relationships) to be a good alternative to the `has_and_belongs_to_many` ActiveRecord helper.  The reasoning behind this is that it is very likely that you will need to change the nature of the association or add to it, and when you are a couple months into a project, this can be very painful if the relationship were initially set up as a `has_and_belongs_to_many` (the second link goes into some detail).  If it is set up initially using a `has_many :through` relationship, then a couple months into the project it's easy to rename the join model or add attributes to it, making it easier for devs to respond to changing requirements. Plan for change.

Answer (score 14):

- **Inverse association**: consider the classic situation user-membership-group. If a user can be a member in many groups, then a group has many members or users, and a user has many groups. But if the user can only be a member in one group, the group still has many members: `class User has_one :group, :through => :membership` but `class Group has_many :members, :through => memberships`. The intermediate model `membership` is useful to keep track of the inverse relationship.
- **Expandability**: a `has_one :through` relationship can easy be expanded and extended to a `has_many :through` relationship