# Use through option on a belongs_to ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, belongs-to

Is there a way to use the `through` option in a belongs_to relationship? The [Rails documentation on belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) doesn't mention `through` as an option, why not? I want to do something like the following:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :lesson_group_id
  belongs_to :lesson_group
  belongs_to :level, through: :lesson_group
end

class LessonGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :level_id
  belongs_to :level
  has_many :lessons
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number
  has_many :lesson_groups
end
```

Then I can do something like `Lesson.first.level`. Using latest stable Rails (3.2.9 as of now).

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Under `has_one`, the Rails documentation says, "This method should only be used if the other class contains the foreign key. If the current class contains the foreign key, then you should use belongs_to instead."

Comment: The documentation for `has_one` also says "Options: [...] - :through
Specifies a Join Model through which to perform the query. Options for :class_name, :primary_key, and :foreign_key are ignored, as the association uses the source reflection. You can only use a :through query through a has_one or belongs_to association on the join model."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [the link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) you gave:

> Specifies a one-to-one association with another class. This method should only **be used if this class contains the foreign key**.

I think you should use `has_one :level, through: :lesson_group`, like following:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :lesson_group_id
  belongs_to :lesson_group
  has_one :level, through: :lesson_group
end

class LessonGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :level_id
  belongs_to :level
  has_many :lessons
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number
  has_many :lesson_groups
end
```

A part of the documentation about the Options for `has_one`:

> **:through**
>
> Specifies a Join Model through which to perform the query. Options for :class_name, :primary_key, and :foreign_key are
> ignored, as the association uses the source reflection. You can only
> use a :through query through a has_one or belongs_to association on
> the join model.

**They talked about that** here:
[Rails has_one :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116017/rails-has-one-through-association)

Comment: That seems to not make sense. `Lesson`'s `belongs_to :lesson_group` exists because it does have the foreign key. Similarly `LessonGroup`'s `belongs_to :level` exists because it has the foreign key. I'll try this, but reluctant to rely on this mechanism even if it works as the documentation doesn't make it clear at all to use `has_one` in this situation.

Comment: I agree, it is not clear for this kind of situation. This may interest you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116017/rails-has-one-through-association

Comment: `belongs_to :through C` does not exist because the current table does not contain the foreign key that point to `C`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Rails 6`, `Ruby 2.6`, I ran into a similar issue where I had a `User` which could belong to many `Organizations`, but always had a `primary_organization` which was the first `Organization` they were assigned to. Originally I had set this with the method:

```
def primary_organization
  organizations.first
end
```

However, that ultimately broke my scope chaining. The above `primary_organization` method can be refactored into a chainable conditional without having to change the `user.primary_organization` syntax:

**user.rb**

```
# has_many: OrganizationUsers > Organizations
# ==================================================================================
has_many    :organization_users,
              class_name:     'OrganizationUser',
              inverse_of:     :user,
              dependent:      :destroy,
              autosave:       true,

has_many    :organizations,
              class_name:     'Organization',
              through:        :organization_users,
              inverse_of:     :organization_users,
              source:         :organization

# *** ADDED IN REFACTOR ***
# has_one: Organization
# shortcut for:
#   • `user.organization_users.first.organization`
#   • `user.organizations.first`
# ==================================================================================
has_one     :primary_organization_user,
              -> {
                order(
                  created_at: :desc
                ).limit(1)
              },
              class_name:     'OrganizationUser',
              inverse_of:     :user

has_one     :primary_organization,
              class_name:     'Organization',
              through:        :primary_organization_user,
              inverse_of:     :organization_users,
              source:         :organization
```

**organization_user.rb**

```
# belongs_to: Organization
# ==================================================================================
belongs_to  :organization,
              class_name:     'Organization',
              inverse_of:     :organization_users

# belongs_to: User
# ==================================================================================
belongs_to  :user,
              class_name:     'User',
              inverse_of:     :organization_users
```

**organization.rb**

```
# has_many: OrganizationUsers > Users
# ==================================================================================
has_many    :organization_users,
              class_name:     'OrganizationUser',
              inverse_of:     :organization,
              autosave:       true,
              dependent:      :destroy

has_many    :users,
              class_name:     'User',
              through:        :organization_users,
              inverse_of:     :organization_users,
              autosave:       true
```