# how to use through in rails model with separate foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a rails app with the models below. I would like to be able to refer to profiles directly from tasks. As I see I should use :through somehow, but I can't figure it out. At the moment let's say if I wanna get the first_name in task model I gotta use task.executor.profile.first_name. Instead of that I would like to use task.executor_profile.first_name.

I need it for ransack where you can refer to the associations with include. If there is an easier solution without having to do the :through association, pls let me know.

UPDATE:

Based on @rlarcombe's I tried delegate but unfortunately Ransack doesn't seem to be supporting that solution, but it's working nicely with rails. Can sby tell me how could I use the :through association in this case?

user.rb

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id", dependent: :destroy
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

task.rb

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is define a couple of [has_one through associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116017/rails-has-one-through-association) on your Task model.

These association definitions should give you what you want:

**app/models/task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"

  has_one :assigner_profile, through: :assigner, source: :profile
  has_one :executor_profile, through: :executor, source: :profile
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**app/models/profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

With these in place, you should now be able to call:

```
task.assigner_profile.first_name
```

and

```
task.executor_profile.first_name
```

These has_one through associations should work correctly with Ransack.

Thanks

Comment: You are right I missed adding the has_one:profile line in user.rb. Unfortunately Ransack doesn't seem to be supporting this delegate solution, but it's working nicely with rails. Can you tell me how could I use the :through association in this case? That might solve this issue.

Comment: I figured out what you were trying to do with Ransack. I have updated my answer, and I think this solution will work. You may want to edit your question, since you refer to my answer which has now been changed. Thanks!

Comment: @SzilardMagyar - just wondering if my latest edit of my answer gives you what you need.?

Comment: Hi @rlarcombe, working on it at the moment, will let you know soon.